# How do I fix the GC cycle caused by a lambda event handler?

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin.ios, garbage-collection, xamarin

Watching [Advanced Memory Management](http://xamarin.com/evolve/2013#session-0w86u7bco2) by Mark Probst and Rodrigo Kumpera, I learned new techniques such as profiling Mono GC and using `WeakReference`.

Yet I still don't understand how to “fix” the Puzzle 2 from 28th minute:

```
public class CustomButton : UIButton {
    public CustomButton () { }
}

public class Puzzle2Controller : UIViewController
{
    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        var button = new CustomButton ();
        View.Add (button);
        button.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) =>
            this.RemoveFromParentViewController ();
    }
}
```

The controller holds a ref to button that holds a ref to event handler that holds a ref to the controller.

One way to break the cycle would be to nullify the button.
Another way is to detach the handler (but we'd have to forsake using lamdas).

Are there other /more elegant/ ways to break the cycle? Can we somehow stick `WeakReference` in here?

Thanks.

Edit: In this case, the button is not even a field. But there is still a cycle, isn't there? It's in Controller's View's Subviews. Do we have to clear them? I'm confused.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cycles *are not usually a problem* in a garbage-collected environment - I must assume from the question that this is somehow different in monotouch? Edit: no, my assumption here remains valid - at 7:50 in the video you link to it demonstrates a cycle being discarded by the "sweep".

Cycles can *usually* be ditched whole-sale, as soon as the entire cycle becomes unreachable. This would be a problem in a *reference-counted* system.

However! With regards your question - does the button (once added) know about the controller? if so, you could get there from `sender`:

```
button.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) =>
            ((UIButton)sender).Parent.RemoveFromParentViewController();
```

This lambda now doesn't involve a captured variable, and doesn't involve a capture context; it doesn't hold any reference to the controller - and actually most compilers will make that a single static handler rather than a handler per usage, so it is more efficient in terms of delegate creations too.

---

Re the context of monotouch specifically, then yes, you'd need to use `WeakReference<T>`:

```
var controller = new WeakReference<Puzzle2Controller>(this);
button.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => {
    var parent = controller.Object;
    if(parent != null) parent.RemoveFromParentViewController();
};
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. This certainly would be an option, but unfortunately `UIView`s don't hold reference to their controllers. If my understanding is correct, cycles in MonoTouch *are* a problem because under-the-hood native ObjC objects use reference counting. (See 21:30)

Comment: @MarcGravell: If the cycle is discarded by the "sweep" must we still  use WeakReference in the above situation?